# How to shorten docker build-push-action image name

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I'm using [docker/build-push-action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) and am trying to find a way to shorten the image name when it gets pushed to github registry.

Currently the docker image name is showing as

```
ghcr.io/organization-name/project-image:latest
```

Can this be shortened to just be the image name and tag without the `ghcr.io/organization-name/`

Answer (score 0):

The name of a docker image tag *needs* to include a registry hostname when you use docker push (unless you are pushing to the default Docker’s public registry located at `registry-1.docker.io`)

It is how `docker push` knows *where* to push to.

That is why a [typical "build and push" step](https://devopsjournal.io/blog/2021/01/06/GitHub-Container-Registry) looks like:

```yaml
name: Build and Push Docker container

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-push:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build -t ghcr.io/<<ACCOUNT NAME>>/<<IMAGE NAME>>:<<VERSION>> .

    - name: Setup GitHub Container Registry
      run: echo "$" | docker login https://ghcr.io -u $ --password-stdin

    - name: push to GitHub Container Registry
      run:  docker push ghcr.io/<<ACCOUNT NAME>>/<<IMAGE NAME>>:<<VERSION>>
```

In your case, (using the `docker/build-push-action`), even if you were to [use a local registry](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/blob/e27bcee4eb9e7b4bc168418e3364c4482120393a/docs/advanced/local-registry.md), you would still need to tag accordingly.

```yaml
-
        name: Build and push to local registry
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: localhost:5000/name/app:latest
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                # still a long tag name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify in the `tags` argument, like:

```
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          push: true
          tags: project-image:latest
```